# How can I force launch the Android app picker for a URI via ADB?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, adb

Running the below command launches the URI in the default app for that URI, falling back on the app picker if there is none.

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://example.com"
```

Which is equivalent to:

```kotlin
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://example.com"))
startActivity(intent)
```

My question is how would I force launch the app picker for the URI instead, via ADB, but equivalent to:

```kotlin
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://example.com"))
val chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, null)
startActivity(chooser)
```

or

```kotlin
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://example.com"))
val chooser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER)
chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, intent)
startActivity(chooser)
```